# What is the significance of being a diagonalizable matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I understand that if a matrix $A$ is diagonalizable, then it is similar to a diagonal matrix $D$. And then the two matrices have the same determinant, rank, and eigenvalues.

I am thinking that there is something more going on. I can see that similarity is an equivalence relation and that usually means that there is something bigger going on.

I am sorry for this sort of vague question, but I am having a hard time seeing the point of diagonalizing matrices.

Comment: Take a matrix $A$ and try to compute $A^n$ for large values of $n$. Now try doing the same for a diagonal matrix. Finally, try to use a diagonalization of $A$ to do this for $A$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Ok, so is this the primary use of diagonalization?

Comment: In the context of solving linear systems, diagonalizing the coefficient matrix corresponds to "decoupling" the unknowns (allowing us to solve separately rather than "simultaneously").

Answer (score 3):

A matrix $A$ represents a linear transformation $T_A$ in a vector space $V$. To say that $A$ is diagonalizable means that there exists a basis in the vector space such that, in this basis, the linear transformation $T_A$ is represented by a diagonal matrix. So, in this basis, the transformation acts as a scaling in the direction of the basis vectors, in general with different scaling factors.

Comment: Since the Question mentions eigenvalues, this can be phrased as a complete basis of the vector space $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: Yes, the basis is formed by the eigenvectors.